# npm ERR! path C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm engaging with angular project. And now i'm referring a tutorial for make a `file upload` part with `firebase`. I have already installed this package `"@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",` for the project. but tutorial explains to install `npm i firebase angularfire2` for the project. I tried for it and got an error like this.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'C:\\Users\\ruwan\\Documents\\projects\\new project\\Hair-4-U-hospital\\Admin\\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\\node_modules\\@firebase\\util\\dist' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\ruwan\\Documents\\projects\\new project\\Hair-4-U-hospital\\Admin\\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\\node_modules\\@firebase\\util\\dist\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\\Users\\ruwan\\Documents\\projects\\new project\\Hair-4-U-hospital\\Admin\\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\\node_modules\\@firebase\\util\\dist',
npm ERR!   parent: 'ngx-admin' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ruwan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-06T02_06_24_456Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture>
```

However I want to make a this sort of component according to tutorial.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
<label for="file">File:</label>
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event)" accept=".png,.jpg" />
`
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }
    upload(event) {
        this.afStorage.upload('/upload/to/this-path', event.target.files[0]);  
    }
}
```

Am I can't get `AngularFireStorage` from where currently exist packages inside the `"@angular/fire": "^5.1.2"`

Comment: 1. It's obviously the path lacks permission. 2. when you're working on a web project, never use folder / file names with spaces.

Comment: @Raptor How I reform this error